# When is my code base large enough to justify using Pycharm PythonDebugger extension?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm thinking about installing the PythonDebugger Extension for Pycharm.
The [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2020.1/cython-speedups.html?utm_campaign=PY&utm_content=2020.1&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product#ec3a551a) says:

> If you have a large code base, using this speedup extension is reasonable.

My codebase has the following amount/size of .py and .pyc files (Measured with [statistics plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4509-statistic)):

[image]

At which size is a code base considered large enough to justify optimization with the PythonDebugger Extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the work to compile the speedups module, there doesn't seem to be a downside to doing that.

I wouldn't spend too much time wondering whether or not to do so for a given code base.